# Pagination in vue visible items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, nuxt.js

I build a pagination component that works fine. But I don't know how to limit the shown items in the v-for loop and show the next items on the next page.

**this is the pagination component:**

```
<template>
<div>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="pagination-item">
            <button
                type="button"
                @click="onClickFirstPage"
                :disabled="isInFirstPage"
            >
                First
            </button>
        </li>

        <li class="pagination-item">
            <button
                type="button"
                @click="onClickPreviousPage"
                :disabled="isInFirstPage"
            >
                Previous
            </button>
        </li>

        <li v-for="page in pages" :key="page.name" class="pagination-item">
            <button @click="onClickPage(page.name)" type="button" :disabled="page.isDisabled" :class="{ active: isPageActive(page.name )}">
                {{ page.name }}
            </button>
        </li>

        <!-- Range of pages -->

        <li>
            <button
                type="button"
                @click="onClickNextPage"
                :disabled="isInLastPage"
            >
                Next
            </button>
        </li>

        <li>
            <button
                type="button"
                @click="onClickLastPage"
                :disabled="isInLastPage"
            >
                Last
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        maxVisibleButtons: {
            type: Number,
            required: false,
            default: 3
        },
        totalPages: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        total: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        currentPage: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        startPage() {
            // When on the first page
            if(this.currentPage === 1) {
                return 1;
            }
            // When on the last page
            if(this.currentPage === this.totalPages) {
                return this.totalPages - this.maxVisibleButtons;
            }
            // When in between
            return this.currentPage - 1;
        },
        pages() {
            const range = [];
            for(let i = this.startPage; i <= Math.min(this.startPage + this.maxVisibleButtons - 1, this.totalPages); i+=1) {
                range.push({
                    name: i,
                    isDisabled: i === this.currentPage
                });
            }
            return range;
        },
        isInFirstPage() {
            return this.currentPage === 1;
        },
        isInLastPage() {
            return this.currentPage === this.totalPages;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onClickFirstPage() {
            this.$emit("pagechanged", 1);
        },
        onClickPreviousPage() {
            this.$emit("pagechanged", this.currentPage - 1);
        },
        onClickPage(page) {
            this.$emit('pagechanged', page);
        },
        onClickNextPage() {
            this.$emit('pagechanged', this.currentPage + 1);
        },
        onClickLastPage() {
            this.$emit('pagechanged', this.totalPages);
        },
        isPageActive(page) {
            return this.currentPage === page;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.pagination {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.pagination-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4AAE9B;
  color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

**my v-for with the items**

```
<div
    v-for="casino in orderBy(filteredCasinos, 'Rating', -1)"
    :key="casino.id + '-filterd'"
    class="casino-card"
    v-show="filteredCasinos.length > 1"
  >
```

At the moment the pagination works when I click to the next page but as I mentioned all items get shown and I want to limit them.

Comment: Try something like `v-for="casino in orderBy(filteredCasinos, 'Rating', -1).slice(currentPage * pageSize, currentPage * pageSize + pageSize)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `computed` property to keep track what should be visible on the current page.

With a `computed` property you can easily introduce a filter on the items. Then just create the functions that sets the current page, and **BAM** - a paginated view of items.

The snippet below does all this, and also gives the ability to choose how many items should be visible on a given page.

Advice:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      currentPage: 1,
      postsPerPage: 10,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // computed property to set the items visible on current page
    currentPagePosts() {
      return this.posts.slice((this.currentPage - 1) * this.postsPerPage, this.currentPage * this.postsPerPage)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // pagination function
    setCurrentPage(direction) {
      if (direction === -1 && this.currentPage > 1) {
        this.currentPage -= 1
      } else if (direction === 1 && this.currentPage < this.posts.length / this.postsPerPage) {
        this.currentPage += 1
      }
    }
  },
  // fetching example data (200 post-like items)
  async mounted() {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    this.posts = await response.json()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="setCurrentPage(-1)">PREV</button>
  <button @click="setCurrentPage(1)">NEXT</button><br /> Current page / max page: {{ currentPage }} / {{ Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage) }}<br />
  <label>Set posts per page: <input v-model="postsPerPage" type="text" /></label>
  <hr />
  <!-- the v-for only lists items from the computed property -->
  <div v-for="post in currentPagePosts" :key="post.id">
    ID: {{ post.id }} Title: {{ post.title }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @foka135 I’m glad that I could help :)